# Why do I get an undefined javascript object property whereas the property does exist

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I have a interrogation regarding Javascript and possibly angular promises.

When I print a whole object:

```
console.log(constants);
```

output:

```
Object {PARENT_NEEDS: Promise}
```

Whereas when I try to print a property of the object as follows:

```
console.log(constants.PARENTS_NEEDS);
```

I see `undefined` as the output...

Can anyone please explain why the second output is undefined?

Here is how I set the object in the UI router configuration:

```
resolve: {
           constants: ['constantsService', function (constantsService) {
           return {PARENT_NEEDS: constantsService.PARENTS_NEEDS};
            }]
         }
```

**edit 1**:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(constants));
```

outputs:

```
{"PARENT_NEEDS":{"$$state":{"status":1,"value":{"PARENTS_TO_CHILDCARE_WORKER":0,"PARENTS_TO_PARENTS":1}}}}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(constants))` produce?

Comment: How can I delete the question? It was indeed a typo and not very relevant therefore.

Comment: My code was not working due to a stupid typo...

Answer (score 4):

It's a typo

```
 Object {PARENT_NEEDS: Promise}//notice single form of PARENT
```

Whereas for `console.log` there is another name mentioned

```
console.log(constants.PARENTS_NEEDS);//plural
```

Comment: You're right. Thank you. My stupid mistake...